# Adding button over camera preview view [BESwiftCamera lib]

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, avfoundation, avcapturesession

Within my swift app, I am using this library to build a custom video camera: https://github.com/bwearley/BESwiftCamera

In my view controller:

```
var camera:BESwiftCamera!
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.attachCamera()
    }

    func attachCamera() {
        do {
            try self.camera.start()
        } catch BESwiftCameraErrorCode.CameraPermission {
            self.showCameraPermissionAlert()
        } catch BESwiftCameraErrorCode.MicrophonePermission {
            self.showMicrophonePermissionAlert()
        } catch {
            self.showUnknownErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let screenRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

        // Configure Camera
        self.camera = BESwiftCamera(withQuality: AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh, position: .Rear, videoEnabled: true)
        self.camera.attachToViewController(self, withFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,screenRect.size.width,screenRect.size.height))
    ...
    }
```

This works well. However, the issue is that it loads over the elements(buttons) I have in my storyboard for this particular view. **How do I load my storyboard elements over the camera preview view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the line in the lib

https://github.com/bwearley/BESwiftCamera/blob/master/BESwiftCamera/BESwiftCamera.swift#L139

```
    vc.view.addSubview(self.view)
```

to

```
    vc.view.insertSubview(self.view, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: its not for the buttons - this is for the camera. doing this will make the camera appear below your storyboard elements